# と (to) vs に (ni) in a phrase like "I am speaking with/to"

Tags: word-choice, particle-に, particle-と

I've heard the following two sentences and I'd like to understand the differences between the two, if any, and when it is appropriate to use one vs the other:

> おいしゃさん**と**はなしています
>
> おいしゃさん**に**はなしています

It is my understanding that these both translate to "I am speaking to the doctor", but what is the difference between `と` and `に` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

おいしゃさん**と**はなしています is "I am talking *with* my doctor", whereas おいしゃさん**に**はなしています is "I am talking *to* my doctor".

The first one with と is natural in most cases, because when you go to a doctor, normally both you and your doctor will talk to each other.

～にはなす can be naturally used when you're talking to something that do not reply to you:

> 彼【かれ】は人形【にんぎょう】に話【はな】している。
>   He is talking to a doll.

...or what is important is whom you are talking to:

> 私【わたし】はあなたにではなく、お医者【いしゃ】さんに話【はな】しています。
>   I am talking not to you, but to my doctor!

Answer (score 2):

It is the same as the difference between talking 'with' someone as opposed to talking 'to' them. おいしゃさんにはなしています can mean that some information is being conveyed to the doctor (basically 'telling' them). と does not imply such a nuance.

お医者{いしゃ｝さんに言｛い｝う would be simply conveying that information, but お医者｛いしゃ｝さんに話｛はな｝す implies discussion relevant to the information might also be taking place.

> 彼はあなたに話していますよ、先生。He's talking to you, doctor.